# why <link> tag in HTML has sorts of rel attribute values in real world

Tags: html

As the [w3school.com](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_rel.asp) describes:

> [image]

tag `link` in HTML5 rules 10 values for attribute `rel`, but I always found many others used in webpages, such as:

```
<link rel="me" type="text/html" href="www.example.com"/>
```

There's no value `me` for attribute `rel`, but it still be used widely.

Why can be that? Any links or advice?

Comment: You shouldn't ever rely on w3schools: http://w3fools.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/links.html#other-link-types) allows custom `rel` attribute values:

> Extensions to the predefined set of link types may be registered in
>   the microformats wiki [existing-rel-values page. [MFREL]](http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values#HTML5_link_type_extensions)
>
> Anyone is free to edit the microformats wiki existing-rel-values page
>   at any time to add a type.

You shouldn't rely on w3schools, because there is a lot of incorrect data there: http://w3fools.com/

Answer (score 1):

These are all types of Micro Formats.

```
rel=me
```

Is Identity consolidation and is used to indicate profile equivalence (The ability for a user to indicate that one or more identities, profiles, URLs across different sites all represent that same user. Also known as: profile aggregation, profile equivalency)

http://microformats.org/wiki/rel-me

Answer (score 0):

`rel="me"` is used on hyperlinks from one page about a person to other pages about that same person.

See: http://microformats.org/wiki/rel-me